# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar esta rayita azul del grafico chart.js?

Tags: php, javascript, chart.js

Tengo esta grafica de la que quiero eliminar esa rayita azul, que es la que marca el color de las columnas. Si hubiera varias columnas con distintos tipos de datos tendría sentido porque marcaria el color de cada columna pero al haber solo un tipo de datos eso sobra.

[image: grafico con un solo tipo de datos]

El grafico esta hecho con chart.js y este es el script de ese grafico:

```
<script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {      
              labels: fechas,  
                datasets: [{
                label: "",//'Ingresos',
                backgroundColor: '#42a5f5',
                borderColor: 'gray',
                data: infectados
                }   
               ]},

         options: {responsive: true,           
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
        }    

        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si esa raya es la leyenda, según [su documentación](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) puedes ocultarla asi:

Dentro de `options:` tienes que poner:

```
legend: {display: false}
```